# count and split into mysql

Tags: mysql, mariadb

just wondering how can I create a function to count the number of \n\n (2 in a row) inside of mysql and split it into diferent alias

Something like:

```
FUNCTION

SELECT COUNT ('paragraphs of a text_field, "\n\n"') AS PRG 
FROM database 
WHERE field_name LIKE '%text%'

WHILE counter < PRG THEN SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX (text_field, '\n\n', 1)
AS C+counter END WHILE 

END FUNCTION;
```

The output should be something like this

For a 3 paragraph text:

```
C1          |C2          |C3
Paragraph 1 |Paragraph 2 |Paragraph 3
```

For a 5 paragraph text:

```
C1          |C2          |C3          |C4          |C5
Paragraph 1 |Paragraph 2 |Paragraph 3 |Paragraph 4 |Paragraph 5
```

Comment: I guess you mean `Paragraph 4 and Paragraph 5`?

Answer (score 0):

MariaDB (and also MySQL) doesn't support split and pivot - it's for sure faster if you do the calculations in your application.

A pure MariaDB/MySQL solution would be a stored procedure, like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE xyz()
BEGIN
  SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(field_name) - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(field_name,"\n\n","")) INTO @a FROM mytbl WHERE fieldname='yourvalue';
  SET @i=1;
  SET @query="SELECT ";
  REPEAT
    SET @query= CONCAT(@query, ' REPLACE(substring_index(field_name, "\n\n", ',@i,'), SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_name,"\n\n", ',@i-1,'), "") AS C',@i,'');
    IF @i < @a THEN 
      SET @query=CONCAT(@query, ",");
    END IF;
    SET @i=@i+1; 
  UNTIL @i > @a END REPEAT; 
  SET @query=CONCAT(@query, " FROM mytbl WHERE field_name='yourvalue'");
  PREPARE my FROM @query;
  EXECUTE my;
END
```

Comment: Perl:  `@paras = split("\n\n", $str);`  A lot less work.  PHP is also a 1-liner.